# Why are my facebook banner ads too small for the ipad in Swift Spritekit?

Tags: ios, swift, banner-ads, facebook-audience-network

The banner ads fit perfectly on the bottom of the screen for the 4s, 5 and 5s but for the iPad, and iPhone 6 and 6 + there too small. What am I doing wrong? I put this code in the GameViewController.swift fie. If you need more info please let me know. Thank you!

```
let adView: FBAdView = FBAdView(placementID:"PLACEMENT_ID",   
adSize:kFBAdSize320x50, rootViewController:self)
adView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 50, width: 320, height: 90)
    self.view.addSubview(adView)
    adView.delegate = self
    FBAdSettings.addTestDevice("TESTDEVICE")
    adView.loadAd()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should work with percentage-sizes:

```
var theWidth = self.frame.width
var theHeight = self.frame.height / 15 //for example. But make the height as you need
```

Instead of hard coded sizes like you did. Then you can use your size like that:

```
adView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 50, width: theWidth, height: theHeight)
```

Comment: I get an error saying GameViewController does not have a member named frame.

Comment: Have you ever tried Facebook audience network in your project?

Comment: @coding22 You need to change it to self.view.frame if you use it inside your GameViewcontroller.

Comment: I got it to work by changing your code a little. I added                                     let width = self.view.frame.size.width
        let height = self.view.frame.size.height / 10 Thank you!